# Print Monitor - Error whil installing

Tags: registry, driver, wdk

I have written a virtual printer driver that includes print monitor dll as well infs. Only problem is that when i try to run the install it with command below, I get **"the specified port is unknown, error 0x0000704.**

rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "aPrinter" /f aprinter.inf  /r "aPrinter Port" /m "aPrinter"

Its kinda strange , cause i can see the aPrinter Port in registry at following place

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Monitors\aPrinter Port

with following string entries

"Driver" "aport.dll"
"name" "aPrinter Port"

Any idea , what i am missing here?

Thanks

Comment: The port names your monitor supports can be stored anywhere you like.  It's up to your monitor to know where it stores port names, and that place must not be the same registry key another monitor uses.  So where does your monitor store the port name when it creates a new port?

Answer (score 0):

When I manually install a printer port, I set it on registry under the print monitor I want to use with a printer.

```
SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Monitors\your_monitor_name\aPrinter Port
```

Comment: Thanks Marco, I dont follow it thou, where can i get the monitor name ? I thought It was aPrinter Port.  Sorry, pretty naive myself. Are you sure it should end like this "\your_monitor_name\aPrinter Port" >